# How to make the application read keys from app.config file of class library dynamically

Tags: wpf, app-config, config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

My requirement is as follows.
1)I want to use the application settings to read a location path and use it in my project to read the files in that folder.
  --- I achieved this by creating a setting with the path and I used to read the path from that settings in the project as follows

```
    Properties.Settings.Default.XMLModelPath
```

2)Now the actual requirement is I want that app.config of the class library to be available in the bin so that I can update the path if there are any changes required later and every time I run the application, the settings of that project should read this file and update its value.

Is there a way to achieve this or suggest any other possible ways.?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
       <configSections>
       <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
           <section name="MyClass.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
       </sectionGroup>
       </configSections>
     <applicationSettings>
        <MyClass.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="XMLModelPath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>C:\Resources\</value>
          </setting>
        </MyClass.Properties.Settings>
     </applicationSettings>
   </configuration>
```

This is my app.config file of the class. I want this to be available in bin and the settings of the project to be updated everytime I run my application.

Comment: the configuration for your library should be placed in the app.config of the calling application

Comment: I have my Application class and A another class. I know if i add a section to the application class App.config I can be able to do that. But I don't want that. I want the app.config file of the another class to be available in Bin and that settings should update its value from the app.config every time I run the application

Comment: Unfortunately, what you want is not possible using app.config. You would have to write your own configuration management helper class to achieve this.